# How to handle percentage sign in table names when fetching data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

Using react and express to fetch and store in JSON format. How can I correctly reference the tables that contain a percentage sign in their name?

```
 componentDidMount() {
   // Get data and sort it by ID, then add it to state
   fetch('http://localhost:5000/citystats')
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => this.setState( { stats: data } ));
 }

 // Table etc
 {this.state.stats.map( (item) => {
 <td>{item.POP%}</td>
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square bracket notation:

```
<td>{item["POP%"]}</td>
```